# Fast scrolling does not work

Tags: scrolling

When I hold middle mouse button in Windows I have fast scrolling down or up. How can I enable it in Chromium? Thanks

Comment: Install this plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Chrome/Chromium extension which does exactly what you want to achieve.

You can get it from here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan

The description says it works on every page except `chrome://` sites (which have extensions disabled) and some XHTML sites, but else than that it should work (according to the description).